# Постучаться на сайт

Tags: cmd

Есть ли возможность создать батник или скрипт по средствам винды который бы стучался на сайтик а точнее запускал скрипт который находится на 
https://www.******.ru/******/******.php
??

Грубо говоря сделать "start https://www.******.ru/******/******.php".bat но только без открытия браузера

Comment: а крон чем не угодил?

Comment: нужно будет установить на большой парк компов, будет сложно(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/204851/10138734